# How do I vary colors in my data points using geom_plot in R?

Tags: r, colors, maps, coordinates

I want my data points to vary by color depending on a factor variable, which is "Status". I want it to be yellow if the value of the data is 1, red if it is 2, and grey if it is 5. What is the best way to approach this?

```
m <- ggplot(data=state)+ 
     geom_polygon(aes(x=long, y=lat, group=group), color="white", fill="black")
m <- m+ theme_bw()
m

# plot data on map #
m <- m+geom_point(data=geo, aes(x= Long, y= Lat), color="Yellow")
m
```

[image: sample data]

Comment: You need to create a variable called status with the specifications that you required, and then put "status" within your aes() call. Consider sharing  a sample of your data using dput() so people can address that.

Comment: I've added a sample of my data- please help!

Comment: Are you working with two different datasets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Status was already present in your data frame, so this should work

```
m <- ggplot(data=state) + 
  geom_polygon(aes(x=long, y=lat, group=group, fill=factor(Status))) +
  theme_bw() + 
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("yellow", "red", "gray"))
m
```